# HTML5 elements gets disappear in android Webview fragment approach

Tags: android, html, android-fragments, webview, android-view

HTML5 elements gets disappear in android Webview fragment approach while changing orientation of screen. There are few observations like it hides only few of the elements randomly. As it's an interactive html page when i click on the screen and all the elements gets appear again.

Just to let you know that the same html5 app is working fine with Android view approach and default browser of android device.

Comment: Did you enabled javascript? You can enable javascript by using "webview.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)" See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5089694/850347

Comment: As I have mentioned it's an interactive html page. So I am already using Javascript for user interaction.