# Enable java script on your browser in Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-layout, android-webview, cordovawebview

When I load **youtube.com** on web view it says **please enable java script on your browser** .

I have done `getJavaScriptEnabled(true)` in my code. Answer?

Comment: You use **g**etJavaScriptEnabled(). I'm pretty sure, you want to use **s**etJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Also point your webview to https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-javascript-enabled to check if it is enabled or not.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling general JavaScript in WebViewClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089578/enabling-general-javascript-in-webviewclient)

Answer (score 6):

```
 WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
 myWebView.loadUrl(" PUT YOUR URL");  //http://www.android.com
 WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

You must add the INTERNET permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file to load
website in your application.

Comment: i did all .still it says that only

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` not `getJavaScriptEnabled(true)`