# Why is the GitHub authorization button in the OAuth flow grayed out?

Tags: android, github, oauth, github-api

I am building an Android app that signs in users to GitHub using OAuth. I followed the instructions [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/basics-of-authentication/) to do so. As the first part of the process, I sent users to the URL

```
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?scope=repo&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID
```

However, when I sign in on my Android device, the `Authorize xxxx` button appears to be greyed out and I can't click it. Does anyone have a clue why this is? (Large screenshot below)

I think the button may not have been greyed out before, the first time I ran the app and signed in. However, I can't tell for sure because I was in a rush.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I pasted the link into Chrome on my computer and the OAuth process worked fine. I noticed the button was greyed out at first, but then became bright green. This got me wondering: was JavaScript enabled by default in the Android WebView? Sure enough, it wasn't. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5089694/4077294) which details how to enable JS. This was the key line that got everything working:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: If i am not using webview , i am using git api , getting the same issue.How can we resolve.  clientId="2e9c1001acbdbecef8a9";
    String clientSecret="3ba4b54a344820154a175b8907d1229013f11add";
    String redirectUrl="futurestudio://calback";,  Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize"
                        +"?client_id="+clientId+"&scope=repo&redirect_url="+redirectUrl));
        startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely support what @james-ko said - **JS has to be enabled for the WebView**.

But sometimes it doesn't help. I found a little bit more info and would be happy to share it here.

Similar story - I have an app which is supposed to login the user with GitHub OAuth, everything works fine except the "Authorise" button - it just stays disabled whatever setting were applied is some cases.

Here is summary:

1. The button is always stays disabled on emulator with API 22 and 23 (I didn't try 24-27 though) regardless of settings and user behaviour.
2. It works well on emulator with API 28 and 29.
3. On the real device Pixel 3 (API 29), the button was disabled initially and nothing was happening for a while. But when I taped the screen twice in random places it got enabled. The app restarting reproduces the situation: initially disabled button --> tap on the screen --> button gets enabled.

Apparently some antifraud mechanism is involved.

But it gives kinda poor experience to the final user it looks like a bug in the app and there is not much what we can do about it :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Safari, but I located a potential cause, the content security policy of the site was set to: `script-src github.githubassets.com`